# An issue with designing my interfaces in C# : Sample Project

Tags: c#, class, oop, design-patterns, interface

I have a problem with designing my interfaces

I have these interfaces :

```
interface IField {

}

interface IScreenField : IField {

}

interface ITable { 
    CustomCollection<IField> CustomCollection { get; set; }
}

interface IScreen
{
    AnotherCustomCollection<IScreenField> AnotherCustomCollection { get; set; }
}
```

`IScreen` interface should inherit from `ITable` but it shows an error that I have to implement a collection of `IField` but I already implement a collection of `IScreenField`

What is the soltuion for this ?

I uploaded a sample project to explain the issue more

You can check the error message in `Screen` class that says :

`Screen` does not implement interface member `ITable.Fields`. `Screen.Fields` cannot implement `ITable.Fields` becuase it does not have the matching return type of `CusomCollection<IField>`

Here is the sample : 
[Sample project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_5XxkO8OJXSw9tx7DJHjD_F0sKkzKJt0)

Comment: post you code... i.e. your interfaces.. and how they are referenced.

Comment: Just because two types, `T1` and `T2` exhibit a particular inheritance or implementation relationship, that does *not* mean that a generic class parametrized by those types, `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` exhibits the *same* relationship. In fact `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` have *no* relationship.

Comment: And even if they did, when it comes to implementing interfaces, the types in the signature (including the return type) must *exactly* match. It's not enough for there to be an inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **This is the answer I posted on your previous post. Reposting it here as-is since your previous question was put on hold before I could
>   submit the answer.**

It’s very difficult to identify the problem without looking at the full code but based on what you have said, I believe, you have implemented `IScreenField` explicitly and the compiler is not able to find any implementation of `IField`.

Checkout following for more info: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000374/Explicit-Interface-VS-Implicit-Interface-in-Csharp

**Update: After looking at the code**

*First of all you need to understand difference between Implicit and Explicit implementations of an Interface:*

> **Implicit:** you access the interface properties and properties as if they were part of the class.
>   **Explicit:** you can only access properties and properties when treating the class as the implemented interface.

The problem with the `Screen` class is that it implements `IScreen` interface, which in-turn implements `ITable` interface. Both these interfaces have a property named `Fields`.

The problem surfaced due to this and you are required to 
**explicitly** implement the `Fields` property in `Screen` class.

**NOTE:** It is irrelevant that you have different return types. Since you have implemented `Fields` property in both interfaces, it is assumed that you are expecting different values when the property is accessed from each of the interfaces.

```
public class Screen : IScreen
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    AnotherCustomCollection<IBaseField> IScreen.Fields
    {
        get
        {
            return default(AnotherCustomCollection<IBaseField>);
        }
    }

    CustomCollection<IField> ITable.Fields
    {
        get
        {
            return default(CustomCollection<IField>);
        }
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Now** how to access them? To access `Fields` property of each of these Interfaces you need to access `Screen` object **as** those interfaces.

> Ex:
>   `var screen = new Screen();`
>
> `var fields = screen.Fields; // Error`
>
> `var fields = (screen as IScreen).Fields; // returns property value of IScreen Fields`
>
> `var fields = (screen as ITable).Fields; // returns property value of ITable Fields`

**Here is the complete code:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/5KS0Xd

Hope this was helpful. All the best and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you so much I understand now what I have to do

Comment: @ShehabMekhlafy, please mark this post as answer if it has helped you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

This description of this example helps you to solve the problem: If IExample2 inherits another Interface, when implementing IExample2 u need to implement
 all the method(properties etc...) that has been declared in interface + the method of inhered interfaces from IExample2. Remember that when you implement an interface you have to implement all of members of that interface (you have to implement even the members of all interfaces that are in chain) and all the returns types has to be the same in interface and in class.

```
interface IExample
{
    void Method1();
}

interface IExample2 : IExample
{
    void Method2();
}

class Screen : IExample2
{
    public void Method2()
    {

    }

    public void Method1()
    {

    }
}
```

Chain Example

```
interface IExample
{
    void Method1();
}

interface IExample2 : IExample
{
    void Method2();
}

interface IExample3 : IExample2
{
    void Method3();
}
```

Comment: yes I know but in my example I want to screen object to be convertable to table object while the screen object has screen fields and table object has db fields.

Comment: @ShehabMekhlafy show your code as its articulated! in this answer

Comment: I already uploaded a sample to google drive can you check it please. that shows the error. I need to be able to convert Screen object to a table object

Comment: if I have property in IExample and IExample2 from with same name but in IExample it's IField but in IExample2 is IBaseField . if you know that IBaseField inherits from IField

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Screen : IScreen
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public AnotherCustomCollection<IBaseField> Fields { get; set; }

    CustomCollection<IField> ITable.Fields
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And apparently the compiler likes that, and if you do something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new List<IScreen>()
        {
            new Screen
            {
                Fields = new AnotherCustomCollection<ScreenInterface.IBaseField>
                {
                    new TextField()
                    {
                        Name = "Hello"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var y = collection.First();

        //Prints "Hello"
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", y.Fields.Select(x => x.Name)));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But, if you are working with the upper interface (ITable)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new List<ITable>() //here
        {
            new Screen
            {
                Fields = new AnotherCustomCollection<ScreenInterface.IBaseField>
                {
                    new TextField()
                    {
                        Name = "Hello"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var y = collection.First();

        //Throws NotSupportedException
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", y.Fields.Select(x => x.Name)));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

My guess is that there isn't the concept of generic inheritance, and that may be proved if you switch the conditional generic parameter of `AnotherCustomCollection` from `IBaseField` to `IField`, and instead of throwing the exception, return the public `Fields` property on `Screen.ITable.Fields`. Compiler will automatically recognize the concrete property and everything will work.

So, for this to work, either define an implicit operator or a custom getter:

```
public class Screen : IScreen
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public AnotherCustomCollection<IBaseField> Fields { get; set; }

    CustomCollection<IField> ITable.Fields
    {
        get
        {
            var customCollection = new CustomCollection<IField>();
            customCollection.AddRange(Fields);
            return customCollection;
        }
    }
}
```